# Проверить наличие символа от начала строки

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Хочу в каждой строке проверять наличие даты. Так как формат дат может быть разный - использую регулярку для проверки наличия символа `|` от начала

Если вставить весь текст, то регулярка `^[^|]*` корректно определяет что оно в первой строке.
Однако если в каждой строке по отдельности искать есть или нет символ `|` - то получается что там даже где нет находит совпадение

```
2022-04-14 17:16:45.896 | ERROR    | app.services.xxx.services:eosd:38 - (<class 'KeyError'>, KeyError('data'), <traceback object at 0x75b968f5c180>)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/env/bin/uvicorn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
    │   │    └ <Command main>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то я не пойму. Во-первых у вас отрицание. Во-вторых от нуля символов и больше. Конечно, этот шаблон всегда выполнится. В общем, у вас шаблон "от нуля и больше символов не равных `|` в начале строки". Такой шаблон имеет смысл только если за ним идёт шаблон с поиском собственно знака `|`. Да и то непонятно в чём смысл, можно сразу с шаблона поиска `|` начинать, без того шаблона.

Comment: `pip install python-dateutil` `from dateutil.parser import parse` `dt = parse(your string) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Посмотрите на результаты [вашего теста](https://regex101.com/r/vqWApZ/1)**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Почему это происходит**: среди выбранных флагов есть флаг `m`, который разрешает оператору `^` находить начало любой строки в тексте. Вы, наверное, подумали, что всё, выражение работает только построчно. Нет, это не так, `[^...]` – отрицающий (негативный) символьный класс, который находит любой символ кроме тех, которые указаны в данном классе. Если вы не укажете символы перевода на новую строку в таком классе, он найдёт переводы строки.

*Но это ещё не всё*. Так как ваше выражение не проверяет наличие символа `|`, любая строка без этого символа будет найдена. Добавьте блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, `(?=\|)`, сразу после `^[^|\r\n]*`.

**Решение**

```
^[^|\r\n]*(?=\|)
```

См. [пример  регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/vqWApZ/3).

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/BTzohD/1 в данном случае некорректно отрабатывает. Как сделать доп проверку на наличие даты? \d{4}-\d{2}.. что то типа этого.. Чтобы начиналась с даты

Comment: @Radzhab `^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d+\.\d+` - см. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/BTzohD/2).

Comment: Я имею в виду как соединить регулярку выше и эту нижнюю

Comment: @Radzhab `^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d+\.\d+)[^\S\r\n]+\|` - так?

Answer (score 0):

Формат дат настолько разный, что трудно подобрать что-то работающее при любом случае. Проще посмотреть на ваши данные и найти что-то, за что можно "зацепиться". Например, в большинстве форматов даты год состоит из четырех цифр, а если вы смотрите файл за этот год, то достаточно найти подстроку "2022".

```
 with open("...", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
# Берем первую часть строки
        dt = line.split(r'|', maxsplit=1)[0]
# и ищем в нем год
        if dt.find('2022') < 0:
            print('False')
        else:
            print('True')
```